# Incorrect syntax in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i getting syntax error near 'adminlogin'. for the following code

what was the error in it?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "adminlogin" (
  `id` intiger (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adminusername` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `adminpassword` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: Dont use quotes for table names,use backticks like for the rest of the columns,also id is integer not intiger

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Use tick(`) in place of double qoute("")

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminlogin` (
`id`  integer(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`adminusername`  VARCHAR (50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`adminpassword`  VARCHAR (50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
```

Your can use this way also, SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

```
ANSI_QUOTES

Treat “"” as an identifier quote character (like the “`” quote character) and not as a
string quote character. You can still use “`” to quote identifiers with this mode 
enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotation marks to quote 
literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change “"” to ‍‍‍“`” and the word "intiger" to "integer". It should work then.